# C++ Timer that runs at back of an C++ application

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu-12.04

I have a C++ application that is running on the foreground. I need a timer that will run at the same time as the application. When the timer reaches zero, I need the timer to popup a window.

I can't use sleep() because the `who` application sleeps. Please advice on how to do this.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your platform? Posix, Windows, Boost etc?

Comment: The correct answer is totally dependent o the GUI framework you are using since you will need to plug some delayed event into the GUIs event queue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're using C++11, I suggest using the [`thread` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

What you probably want is either [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) or [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until), which can be called in the context your timer thread.

Something like this...

```
std::thread timer([]() {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
  std::cout << "hello, world!" << std::endl;
});
std::cout << "thread begun..." << std::endl;
timer.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading the [Boost](http://www.boost.org) libraries and then using [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-boostthreads-library/184401518) extremely simple tutorial on creating a boost thread.

If you don't feel like taking the time to download/install/configure Boost, then use [Windows threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438/Introduction-to-Multi-threaded-Code). (I'm assuming that you are trying to use `sleep()` that you are on Windows). Windows threads are more complicated to understand than Boost threads, though.

In the actual program you'll want to include something like this (using Boost as an example):

```
void timer() {

    sleep(x);
    //Whatever code here to make your popup window.
    return NULL;
}

int main() {

    boost::thread prgmTimer(&timer);
    //Regular code here.
    //prgmTimer.join(); //Remove the comment on that command if you want something to
                        //to happen after your timer runs down and only if your
                        //timer runs down. (Ex. the program exits).
    return 0;
}
```